# Python Flask SQL Register Login Page "hash must be unicode or bytes, not long"

Tags: python

Im trying to create a login / register page.  My register page works and I see the information and hashed passwords added.  When I try to login, I get "hash must be unicode or bytes, not long" flashed.  Please help!

```
    @app.route('/login/', methods=['GET','POST'])
    def login():
        try:
            c,conn = connection()

            if request.method == 'POST':

                data = c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s",
                        thwart(request.form['username']))

                if sha256_crypt.verify(request.form['password'], data):
                    session['logged_in'] = True
                    session['username'] = request.form['username']
                    flash('You are now logged in.'+str(session['username']))
                    return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))

            else:
                error = 'Invalid credentials. Try again'

            return render_template('login.html', error=error)
        except Exception, e:
                flash(e)
------------------------------------------------------------------

     import MySQLdb

     def connection():
         conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                                user = "root",
                                passwd = "julie774",
                                db = "PYTHONTUT")
         c = conn.cursor()

         return c, conn
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> data = c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s",
>                           thwart(request.form['username']))

`cursor.execute` just executes the query and returns the number of affected rows. (see pydoc of cursor.execute). Thus in your `data` variable you have the number of found rows.

Instead you have to fetch the data from the cursor. Also since you are requesting all the columns from user (`*`), you will have to extract only a particular column (the index of it — see the end note).

```
c.execute("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = %s",
                    thwart(request.form['username']))
data = c.fetchone()
# c.fetchone() returns None if no row has been found

if sha256_crypt.verify(request.form['password'], data[0]):
    ...
```

In your example you are connecting to database without specifying the type of the cursor, thus `c.fetchone()` will return a tuple (for example `(1L, 'John Doe', '392347')`). And to select particular column you have to use numerical index — `data[1]` to retrieve `'John Doe'`.

If you want named dictionary instead, you will have to specify it when connecting to db.

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                       user = "root",
                       passwd = "***",
                       db = "PYTHONTUT",
                       cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor
                       )
```

Then `c.fetchone()` will return a `dict` instead (e.g. `{'id': 1L, 'name': 'John Doe', 'password': '392347'}`) so you can use more readable `data['name']` etc.